# BeanMap to HashMap conversion?

Tags: java, javabeans

What is the easiest and most efficient way of converting a `List<BeanMap>` to a `List <HashMap<String,String>>`?

The BeanMap is based on an underlying POJO with 2 fields: 1 string, 1 date

Comment: what would you like the map to map, i.e. what would be the key and value?

Comment: K = field name of Bean,V = value of field in bean. SO basically it is a copy from 1 map to other

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`BeanMap`](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api/org/apache/commons/collections/BeanMap.html) implements `Map<String, Object>`, so you could just treat it as such.

```
List<BeanMap> beanMaps = getItSomehow();
List<Map<String, String>> maps = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

for (BeanMap beanMap : beanMaps) {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    for (Object o : beanMap.entrySet()) { // It's not parameterized :(
        Map.Entry<String, Object> entry = (Map.Entry<String, Object>) o;
        String key = entry.getKey();
        Object value = entry.getValue();
        map.put(key, value != null ? String.valueOf(value) : null);
    }

    maps.add(map);
}

// ...
```